# EmberJS - Observing changes in an {{input}}-Helper in a controller

Tags: ember.js

i have a {{input}}-helper in my template and i want to fire a method in the controller for every change in the {{input}}-helper.

application.hbs

```
<div class="page" id="main">
    {{input type="text" id="note-title" value=noteTitle action="createNote"}}
</div>
```

application_controller.js

```
YeoApp.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        searchTextChanged: function() {
            // this method should be called whenever
            // the input value changes, but somehow it doesn't work

        }.observes("noteTitle"),
        anotherMethod: function() {
            this.set("noteTitle", "Test!");
            //even this doesn't fire the observer when called
        }
    }
});
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance. Don't be afraid to ask questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that using observes inside of the `actions` hash don't work. You need to extract the `searchTextChanged` outside of that object:

```
YeoApp.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  searchTextChanged: function() {
    // this method should be called whenever
    // the input value changes, but somehow it doesn't work
  }.observes("noteTitle"),
  actions: {        
    anotherMethod: function() {
      this.set("noteTitle", "Test!");
      //even this doesn't fire the observer when called
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Ember 2 has a nice solution:
`{{input key-press="action"}}`

See the [docs](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/templates/input-helpers/)

Comment: This is helpful, but not as helpful as some code / example.